# On Warframe, does the Brokk Hammer Skin count as a new weapon?

Tags: warframe

I want to make the Fragor. But Recently, I found the Brokk  Hammer Skin. My friend says I need to have the Fragor to use the skin, but I do not want make the Fragor, and then realize that I do not need it to use the Brokk Hammer Skin.

Comment: You want to make the Fragor, but you do not want to make the Fragor?

Comment: I want to make it, but I want to know if the Brokk Hammer Skin counts as a new weapon, because I do not want to have to collect more Gallium, seeing that it is difficult to find.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You need to make a Fragor.**

Skins are precisely that: *skins* that change the appearance of an existing weapon. Keep in mind that unlike most other weapon skins the Brokk actually changes the Fragor's stats, so in that sense it's almost more like the weapon equivalent of one of the alternate warframe helmets.

The skin isn't a weapon itself; it's almost like a special mod that changes the weapon's appearance and stats (just like a fire damage mod would change the weapon's appearance by adding a fire effect to it and change its damage by adding a fire effect). Brokk is a *skin*, not a weapon. Weapons have levels, skins don't. Brokk doesn't have levels and will not affect your Fragor's levels.

Basically, when you equip Fragor you can choose whether it looks like a regular Fragor or like a Brokk. It's still a Fragor; you're not changing what it *is*, only what it *looks like*.

Comment: But do I still need to have the Fragor? And, does any existing levels on the Fragor I get carry over to the Brokk?

Comment: @ShadowZorgon I edited my answer. Brokk **is not a weapon**. It's like a special 0-cost mod that can only be placed in Fragor but doesn't take up a mod slot. Yes you need a Fragor. There's no "carry over"; Brokk is just a different visual for Fragor that can be turned on and off from your arsenal any time you want.

Comment: And it gives the stat changes. Thanks! Just did not want to have to re-spend all the resources.

Answer (score 0):

As Oblivious Sage has stated as well, you must have crafted or bought the Fragor in order to use the Brokk Hammer weapon skin. Crafting the latter will require mostly the same resources as the original weapon though.

A weapon skin changes the appearance of a particular applicable weapon, though half of these skins (at the time of this post) are for purely cosmetic purposes. In this case however, applying the Brokk Hammer skin increases the Fragor's swing speed by 5%, and slows down its charge attack rate by 10%. There are [four weapon skins](http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Weapon_Skin_Blueprints) in total right now, two of which have stat changing effects (Brokk Hammer and Manticore Hammer). There are purely cosmetic skins for sentinels as well, though they must be purchased for platinum.

A weapon skin by itself *does not* count as a separate weapon. It's essentially clothing or dress up for the weapon in question. So, regardless of equipping this skin, the Fragor's affinity levels will be maintained. Basically, after equipping the Fragor, you'll have the option of applying this skin, provided you already own one. It's your choice on deciding whether the cosmetic and stat changes are worth it.